# React/ Redux : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I've been trying to solve this for a while. I'm following a YouTube tutorial from about a year ago, so the Redux version may be to blame for this.

```html
export const signupUser = (newUserData, history) =>(dispatch) =>{
    dispatch({type: LOADING_UI});
    axios.post('/signup', newUserData)
            .then(res =>{
                setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token);
                dispatch(getUserData());
                dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS}); //in case there are any errors on form prior to redirecting to home page
                this.props.history.push('/');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({
                  type: SET_ERRORS,
                  payload: err.response.data
                });
              });
}
```

The source is in the catch block:

```html
|             .catch(err => {
  14 |                 dispatch({
  15 |                   type: SET_ERRORS,
> 16 |                   payload: err.response.data
  17 |                 });
  18 |               });
  19 | }
```

This is the complied version from the error message:

```html
  1317 |   }).catch(err => {
  1318 |     dispatch({
  1319 |       type: _types__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["SET_ERRORS"],
> 1320 |       payload: err.response.data
       |                             ^  1321 |     });
  1322 |   });
  1323 | };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've gone thorugh a few similar questions, but could not solve the issue.

Comment: Try logging `err.response` value and see if `data` property exists.

Answer (score 0):

Axios returns different error types, which need to be handled differently. You may not be getting a "response" error. You could try the following:

```
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.response) {
      console.log(err.response.data);
      console.log(err.response.status);
      console.log(err.response.headers);
    } else if (err.request) {
      console.log(err.request);
    } else {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
```

See: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors